# Reading data from Website using C#

Tags: c#, web, webserver

I have a website named:

```
string url="http://180.92.171.80/ffs/data-flow-list-based/flood-forecasted-site/"
```

When I give the station name, River name, Basin name, It returns me present Water level. I want to do it in C#. I can read HTML code from `C#`. But there is no value in HTML. Where to start or how I can do it easily? Anyone have any idea?

Comment: Do you have URL which accepts necessary parameters and returns Water level, OR are you asking us to find such URL?

Comment: I have necessary parameters but I want to embedd in C# code.

Comment: You are trying to get the data from a webpage by modifying the link to it. Well it's not a web service that you are calling and so the returned data will be in html, if you are asking that if you need to parse the html returned, then yes you have to.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the WebClient class. You can use the DownloadString() method to get the html from your url as a string.

```
WebClient client = new WebClient ();
string reply = client.DownloadString (address);
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fhd1f0sw.aspx

Comment: I have tried it. But it return me the html code that doesnot contain Water level Data.

Comment: Where does the water level data come from?

Comment: string url ="http://180.92.171.80/ffs/data-flow-list-based/"
Here when I select state, basin, district and river name, it automatically update and show water level.

Comment: You need to put the parameters into the URL that will take you to the page, with the info you want. It may help to browse to the page in your web browser, then copy the URL into your code.